# Customize pagination links in CLinkPager

Tags: yii, pagination

- I am using CLinkPager and need to customize the pagination links url.
- Need to add #test in the url of the pagination links.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement custom class extends CLinkPager and override `createPageUrl()` mentod there:

```
class MyLinkPager extends CLInkPager(){

    public $linkHash = '';

    protected function createPageUrl($page)
    {
        $url = $this->getPages()->createPageUrl($this->getController(),$page);

        if($this->linkHash)
            $url = $url.'#'.$this->linkHash;

        return $url;
    }
}
```

Put file with this class in extension folder and dont forget add this folder in `import` in config (`main.php`):

```
'import'=>array(
    'application.extensions.*',
    ...
)
```

And further, for example in CGrigView configuration, set this pager class:

```
this->widget(
    'zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', 
    array(
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'pager'=>array(
            'class'=>'MyLinkPager',
            'linkHash'=>'test'
        ),
    ...
    )
)
```